# 0X10 Symbol In C not showing in array

Tags: c, pointers, printing, hex, ascii

I had this problem for a while now and I'm not sure what to do next. Basically I am trying to add the ASCII Symbol of the hex value 0x10 to my 2d array. This ASCII symbol will then work as one of the 4 directions (in this case right) of a "robot". The content of the 2d array is a maze which is gather from the content of a txt file. I have read the content of the file and the printing of the array both with pointer. However, when I print the 2d array the maze shows up perfectly but the ASCII Symbol 0x10 does not show at all.

I believe that the problem might come from using pointers but I could be wrong.

This is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* X and Y will be used to define the size of the maze*/
#define X 20
#define Y 40

/*Structures*/
typedef struct
{
    char maze[X][Y];
    char robot;
    int x,y;
    
}Cords;

/*---Function Prototype---*/
void save_maze(Cords*); 
void print_maze(Cords*);

/*Function to Save the maze file into the array*/
void save_maze(Cords* border)
{
    int i,j,k,x,y;
    char wall;
    int row,col;
    row=X;
    col=Y;
        border->robot = 0x10;
    FILE *FileMaze;
    
    FileMaze = fopen("maze.txt","r");
    if (FileMaze == NULL) 
    {
    printf("\n The file is missing");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("File was open! \n");
        while(fscanf(FileMaze,"%d %d %c",&x,&y,&wall) == 3)
        {
             border->maze[x][y] = wall; 
        }
    }
    /*Here I am trying to set the ASCII 0x10*/

    border->maze[1][2] = border->robot; 

    fclose(FileMaze);
    printf("The Maze has been saved! \n");
    
}

/* This fuction takes the value of maze by reference using a pointer */

void print_maze(Cords* border)
{
    int i,j,k,x,y;
    
    int row,col;
    row=X;
    col=Y;
    for (i = 0; i <row ; i++) 
    {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            if(border->maze[i][j] != 'x' && border->maze[i][j] != 'o' && border->maze[i][j] != 'S' && border->maze[i][j] != 'E')
            {
                /*blank spaces is where the "robot" can move around*/

                border->maze[i][j] = ' ';
            } 
            
            printf("%2c",border->maze[i][j]);
            
        }
        printf("\n\r");
    }
```

For clarification the content of the file is as follow:

- "X" are the walls of the maze.
- "o" are the coins in the maze.
- "S" is the start of the maze.
- "E" is the exit of the maze.

The rest of the code is just my main where I call in both of these function.

Comment: Having a `print` function that modifies its arguments is a real bad idea. And a `save` function that `load`s is confusing. Also the code in print looks suspisciously like it lets only some characters through...

Comment: ASCII code 0x10 is the 'DLE' control character which is not in the normal, printable range.

Comment: You should change `while(fscanf(FileMaze,"%d %d %c",&x,&y,&wall)!= EOF)` to `while(fscanf(FileMaze,"%d %d %c",&x,&y,&wall)==3)` Otherwise you will not detect if invalid input was entered and will end up in an infinite loop.

Comment: That `if(border->maze[i][j] != 'x' && border->maze[i][j] != 'o' && border->maze[i][j] != 'S' && border->maze[i][j] != 'E')` block will explicitly change the robot character (or any character other than 'x', 'o', 'S' and 'E') to a space, so why would you expect to be printed as anything other than a space?

Answer (score 1):

Ascii character 0x10 is not visible when printed, try `printf("%3d",border->maze[i][j]);`. This will print each cell as a number instead of a character.

Or you can change the character to a visible character: https://ss64.com/ascii.html

Comment: The second option is what you need here. Printing with `"%3d"` is probably not helpful here. Replace `0X10` with`'@'` should fix it.

Comment: I have tried printing with "%3d" but it has not help in this case.  I have also tried by replacing "0x10" to "@" but i does not print either.

Comment: @Gerhardh you're right of course. I somehow forgot the rules of integer promotion in variadic functions

Comment: @BenjaminAlonso Are you sure you used single quotes? `'@'` Single quotes defines a character whereas double quotes defines a string.

Comment: @BenjaminAlonso Well you *are* replacing anything other than `'x'`, `'o'`, `'S'` and `'E'` with a space in `print_maze()`, so....

Answer (score 0):

`print_maze()` is modifying each element of the maze, replacing anything other than `'x'`, `'o'`, `'S'` and `'E'` with a space (`' '`) before it prints that element.

If you only want to print the maze and not modify it while printing, assign a local variable to the value of the element of the maze and modify the variable instead of modifying the element of the maze:

```
            char elem = border->maze[i][j];

            if(elem != 'x' && elem != 'o' && elem != 'S' && elem != 'E')
            {
                /*blank spaces is where the "robot" can move around*/

                elem = ' ';
            } 
            
            printf("%2c",elem);
```

If you want to print the robot character, do not replace it with a space:

```
            if(elem != 'x' && elem != 'o' && elem != 'S' && elem != 'E' && elem != border->robot)
```

The ASCII character code 0x10 might not be printable on your terminal. You could use a "normal" printable character for such as `'>'` for the robot. Perhaps use ASCII characters `'>'`, `'<'`, `'^'` and `'v'` for the different directions.